# How to setup Roundcube on an Ubuntu Desktop server?

Tags: email, ubuntu-12.04, webserver, owncloud

I have recently created a home server to put OwnCloud, an open source cloud storage program, on and to host some small files. However I am seeking to add webmail with Roundcube, either with the OwnCloud plugin or a seperate place in the web server. The server is a laptop running Ubuntu desktop 12.04 LTS adapted for use as a server. I cannot figure out either how to install OwnCloud plugins from apps.owncloud.com or to install Roundcube with APT. (I installed Owncloud using APT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to install Roundcube manually.

Assuming you have MySQL installed and configured along with the other prerequisites such as PHP. Head to the Roundcube web site and grab a copy. Unpack it where the web server user can read/write and follow the instructions.

I think the last install of OwnCloud I did similarly. Often the packaged versions of such apps are out of date - sometimes by years.

Comment: That makes sense-when I tried to update owncloud through Updater app it didn't work. do you mean the "web installer" type install? Thanks.

Comment: The new OwnCloud web installer is very easy to use and lets me install OwnCloud apps much more easily. It also updates properly! Roundcube is a bit more complicated but is still OK.